# Hibernate returned null for @OneToOne Field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

написал код 
Пользователь:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    //...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn("resume_id)
    private Resume resume;
    //...
    public Resume getResume() {
        return resume;
    }
}
```

Резюме:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resume")
public class Resume {
//...
}
```

Создаю в контроллере новое резюме и добавляю к пользователю:

```
@PostMapping("/resume")
public String addResume(@RequestParam //... @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    if (user.getResume() != null) {
        return "redirect:/profile";
    }
    Resume resume = new Resume();
    resume.setEducation(education);
    //Проставляю поля...
    resumeRepo.save(resume);
    user.setResume(resume);
    userRepo.save;
    return "profile";
}
```

Пробовал менять местами .save репозиториев, не помогло

Заходя в бд вижу, что резюме успешно создано с id = 2(допустим) а в таблице пользователя в resume_id тоже стоит 2. 
Но при попытке в коде обратиться к user.getResume() он отдает null

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "resume_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")
 @OneToOne
 private Resume resume;

Comment: работает ?!!!!?

Comment: попробуйте userRepo.saveAndFlush()

Comment: Нет, не заработало. saveAndFlush() тоже попробовал

Comment: https://pastebin.com/B0evUp0B вот что вышло